# Как разделить переменную на отдельные части

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим у меня есть переменная, которая обозначает цвет
И как мне отделить их на три разные, по типу R, G, B

```
GG = 100,20,230
R =
G =
B =
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как `GG` это `tuple`:

```
R = GG[0]
G = GG[1]
B = GG[2]
```

Comment: Это не python :) В нём достаточно `R, G, B = GG`

Comment: @splash58 согласен, этот вариант лучше. Но в вопросе указаны три строки, поэтому я решил сделать так же.

Comment: мне так кажется, что писать с огрехами код в ответе, потому что и так работает - плохая практика. Все-таки, ответы на стеке должны, в том числе, показывать аккуратный код. Народ учится, и лучше, чтоб учился на красивых (правильных) образцах